# textpad regexp replace all ampersands in url string for href

Tags: regex, textpad

Using textpad only, what regexp will find & amps; or &'s inside an href and replace them temporarily (even though I know the correct url encoding would have them be left as entities).. with a key that can be used later after TIDYING up. What I have now finds the first instance, but url params with multiple &'s don't get cleaned right, and doesn't account for items that are properly encoded with & amp; s already.

Here's what I have:

```
FIND WHAT: \(<a href="[^"]+?\)&

REPLACE WITH: \1-AMP-
```

What I want is something that will take this:

```
<A HREF="http://domain/boo.php?dross1=foo&dross2=bar&amp;dross3=baz&dross4=alpha&dross5=beta&amp;dross6=delta">
```

and turn it into this:

```
<A HREF="http://domain/boo.php?dross1=foo-AMP-dross2=bar-AMPENT-dross3=baz-AMP-dross4=alpha-AMP-dross5=beta-AMPENT-dross6=delta">
```

That way I can quickly search and replace to revert them back to their initial sate afterwards since this is only for validating, not for saving.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's problematic to narrow down only replacing ampersands *within links* - it can be done with lookaheads, but I don't know if textpad supports those.

Comment: i could do two sep actions if that simplifies it? but yeah, both would have to be just in links, otherwise inline js (sigh to that) gets && biffed and so does & ampeveryotherentity;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how this would be achieved in textpad, however in powershell this could be done as:

```
$String ='<A HREF="http://domain/boo.php?dross1=foo&dross2=bar&amp;dross3=baz&dross4=alpha&dross5=beta&amp;dross6=delta">'
$String -replace '(?<=<a[^<>]*href="[^"<> ]*?)&amp;',  "-AMP-"
```

yields

```
<A HREF="http://domain/boo.php?dross1=foo&dross2=bar-AMP-dross3=baz&dross4=alpha&dross5=beta-AMP-dross6=delta">
```

Dissecting the regex:

1. The look around (?<= .... ) first validates that you're a anchor tag
2. moves through that tag until it finds the href name
3. moves through the string of non ", <, >, space characters looking for &
4. All & strings are then found and replaced.